# postdelayed in camerax basic

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

I am looking at the CameraX Basic app provided by google and a lot of times, the postDelayed function is used in the code but I don't understand how it works and what it does (I am fairly new to Kotlin). I looked up postDelayed online and all the examples/explanations use java where a Runnable anonymous class is provided with overriding the run method but the code in the app doesn't have the run method which I don't understand why (since is it not required to be overridden? And even if it isn't require to be overridden, how is it working without any functions/methods:

Examples from CameraX Basic App:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
// Before setting full screen flags, we must wait a bit to let UI settle; otherwise, we may
        // be trying to set app to immersive mode before it's ready and the flags do not stick
        container.postDelayed({
            container.systemUiVisibility = FLAGS_FULLSCREEN
        }, IMMERSIVE_FLAG_TIMEOUT)
```

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
// Display flash animation to indicate that photo was captured
                    container.postDelayed({
                        container.foreground = ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)
                        container.postDelayed(
                                { container.foreground = null }, ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS)
                    }, ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS)
```

Can someone explain how these work and since they are passing a Runnable without a run().

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the [`View.postDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method takes a `Runnable` which represents the action to be executed, it also takes a `long` value representing the delay in milliseconds before the action should be executed.

So you can write this in kotlin

```
view.postDelayed(object: Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        // do something
    }
}, 1_000)
```

Given that the `Runnable` interface only has a single method to override, `run()`, you can convert it to a lambda when using it, you just provide the body of the `run()` method and the compiler understands that it's the implementation of the `run()` method of a `Runnable` instance.

```
view.postDelayed({
    // do something
}, 1_000)
```

If you're familiar with Java, then this should look familiar since Java supports this as well (I believe from version 8). You should read up on [lambdas and higher-order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) as they're a very useful feature in Kotlin.